# Swing JDialog bug?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to create my own dialog by extending the JDialog class
this is the code i used to start:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class ColorManager extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ColorManager(){
        super();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

when i try to run the code it works fine but i'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultCloseOperation must be one of: DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, HIDE_ON_CLOSE, or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
```

i read that there were problems with `WINDOWS_EXIT` or something like that but the parameter i pass should do the job.
the thing that makes it even weirder is that when i change my class so it will contain a `JDialog` field instead of extending it, it seems to work just fine.
I asked a friend to test this on his computer and the code did not throw the exception, he is using jre version 1.6.022 and I'm using 1.6.022 both of us are using 64 bit.

so what did i do wrong? or is that a bug in the JRE?

Edit: forgot to mention, I'm using eclipse
Edit2: i tried the same code in Netbeans and it works fine, what could be my problem??

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace for the exception.

Comment: From my own experiences with bugs in my programs, the chances of this being a bug in Java are quite low. Chances that it's a bug in your code is quite high, orders of magnitude higher.  I suggest that you create and post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) so we can test and modify the code ourselves.

Comment: In all likelihood the bug is in code that you're not showing us.  Again, an SSCCE would offer you your best bet for getting a quick and complete solution here.

Comment: ok i think i found out what i did wrong. i pasted the code to a new project and tested it, same thing happened, then i created a main function that created the dialog, it works fine now. i guess that when i try running it without a main just to view the dialog it tries to run it as java beans and that whats causing the exception i guess, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the methods you call in constructor **should be called on the EDT thread**. It is not advised to do it inside the constructor, but if you insist make sure it runs on Swing (EDT) thread such as:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class ColorManager extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ColorManager(){
        super();
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                this.pack();
                this.setVisible(true);
             }
         });
    }
}
```

IMO the best way do accomplish it would be to move this into separate method and then call it after creating your `ColorManager` instance.

When using Swing you should always adhere to Swing threading rules. More information can be found at

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Answer (score -1):

All the  above solution are great, I also had very disturbing moment with show the `JDialog`.

On NETBEAN 8.2 just left click the `JFrame` and choose properties, then set the `defaultCloseOperation` Property ... Usually the first on the list,

do the same for the `JDialog`

... Anyway that,s my own experience